# Spark custom estimator using package-private DefaultParamsWriter

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm working on implementing a custom estimator to extend mllib, and need to use a package-private util class DefaultParamsWriter. Can I change the package name of my class to org.apache.spark.ml package and build it with other code as a jar? Will there be any problem to run the scala app on spark cluster?

Comment: Why not just copy the code into your app? Spark is open source.

Comment: `DefaultParamsWriter` is child of public abstract class `MLWriter`, maybe it is enough to extends `MLWriter` for you?